# API for a function, should I throw exception?

Tags: c#

I have to create a method

```
CalculateMean(int[] x)
```

If the input is an empty array, should I return 0 (or some number), or throw exception?

Comment: As a user of your API, what would you expect to happen in that case? There isn't exactly a right or wrong answer.

Comment: As a user, I get incorrect results if I return 1 or 0 for empty input

Comment: You need to decide if an empty array is valid input into your method.  Does an empty input differ from null or should they be treated the same.  Once you can answer these you're most of the way to deciding what to do.

Comment: In this case you should definitely not return 1 or 0 for empty input.  That makes absolutely no sense as 1 and 0 could be valid return values.

Comment: Given that the question appears to be about computing the arithmetic mean with zero length input (which is a divide by zero), the question appears be about how to handle invalid input, rather than whether it is worth dealing with valid edge or degenerate cases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my opinion, you should definitely throw an exception (unless the return type is nullable).

Since the empty array has no mean, there is no correct number that a `CalculateMean` method could return when called on the empty array. Returning any number would be incorrect.

Since returning any number would be incorrect, there are only two options that *would* be correct:

- throw an exception, or
- make the return type of `CalculateMean` nullable, and return `null`.

Whatever you do, make sure that the documentation for `CalculateMean` states exactly what it does when you pass it an empty array.

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb358946(v=vs.110).aspx      This implementation throws an unchecked error so the caller does not need to have try catch blocks.

Comment: C# does not have checked exceptions, Java does.